# How to implement a background with a gradient border and a gradient background

Tags: flutter, tabbar, indicator

What I want to implement is like this style. Pls see the picture below.
[Need show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXy9B.png)

The border is gradient, start color is

```
#08FFFB
```

and the end color is

```
#FF4EEC
```

.And the background which like black is also gradient which start color is

```
#3A3A3A
```

and the end color is

```
#0B0B0B
```

The corner radius is 16.

I want to use it as a custom indicator in TabBar component. So, I custom the

```
indicator
```

like this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List\<String\> list = \["全部","读书","电影", "小说"\];

return Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
child: Container(
width: double.infinity,
height: 62,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.white,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
child: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 13, 25, 13),
child: TabBar(
labelColor: Colors.white,
unselectedLabelColor: YYSColors.yysTextColor(),
isScrollable: true,
indicator: new BoxDecoration(
gradient: LinearGradient(
begin: Alignment.topCenter,
end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
colors: \<Color\>\[
Color(int.parse("FF3A3A3A", radix: 16)),
Color(int.parse("FF2B2B2B", radix: 16))
\],
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
border: new Border.all(
color:  Color(int.parse("FF08FFFB", radix: 16)), width: 2),
),
tabs: list
.map((String arenaType) {
return Tab(text: arenaType);
}).toList(),
),
),
),
)，
);
}
```

I have tried to use image in BoxDecoration but it is not work. And I also get some informations from internet that maybe I can use a custom Widget extends Decoration, but I need to override paint() method. It is too difficulty to me. So I came here to ask for help. Thanks a lot.

It is my frist question at here. So the format is not that good. Pls forgive me.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. If we just create a component that can show it as the picture is easy. But it needs to be used with TabBar => indicator, it needs to be a Widget that extends the Decoration class. So I can't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Design a gradient container.
2. Using Stack take the second container.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  If we just create a component that can show it as the picture is easy. But it needs to be used with TabBar => indicator, it needs to be a Widget that extends the  Decoration class. So I can't do it like this way.

Answer (score 0):

Defining gradient for container is pretty straight forward,
For border gradient please follow this good blog.
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-simple-gradient-borders-flutter/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If we just create a component that can show it as the picture is easy. But it needs to be used with TabBar => indicator, it needs to be a Widget that extends the Decoration class. So I can't do it like this way.